# add the value of a cell to another cell and then clear it

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have been unable to find a way to create a kind a score tracker.

I want to have 2 cells... one to capture a value and one to keep a running total.

This is the scenario:

Cell B1 will contain a running total of points scored.
Cell A1 will allow the user to input a score.

I need The value entered in A1 to be added to the current total in B1.
Once B1 has been updated with the added value, cell A1 should be cleared to be ready for then next score.

Can this be done?

Thanks to all for any ideas you can offer.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You are welcome.

Comment: You will most likely need a macro for this. Calculations are made in real time, so assuming there's a calculation relating A1 and A2, if you were to clear cell A1 after adding it to B1, B1's value would change again due to A1 being blank again. A macro, on the other hand, can perform operations step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the one of the worksheet modules ...

```
Private bIgnoreEvent As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If bIgnoreEvent Then Exit Sub
    bIgnoreEvent = True
    Cells(1, 2) = Cells(1, 2) + Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(1, 1) = ""
    bIgnoreEvent = False
End Sub
```

By all means try it without the `bIgnoreEvent` bit as follows so you can see why it is necessary. I recommend you do this after you have saved your current work ...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells(1, 2) = Cells(1, 2) + Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(1, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

**... because it WILL CRASH EXCEL ... you have been warned!**

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... I have very little knowledge about macros How to write them or make them work.
I'm assuming that where you you state Cells(1, 2) the 1 and 2 should be change to the actual cells like Cells(A1, A2) =Cells(A1, A2) + Cells(A1, A1) Followed by Cells(A1, A1) = ""

Comment: The actual Running total cell in my sheet is Cell A2 and the input cell is below it in cell A8. I can send you my test worksheet if you wish.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. `Cells(x,y)` means the cell at row `x`, column `y` only we use a number for both instead of a letter for the column ... eg `cells(1,1)` is the same as cell `A1`. Cell `B1` is `cells(1,2)`, and `cells(3,1)` is the same as cell `A3`.